# How to validate latitude and longitude separately in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
if ((get.latitude).match(/((\d+)+(\.\d+))$/))
    Analytics_Latitude = get.latitude;
else
    Analytics_Latitude = 'undefined';

if ((get.longitude).match(/((\d+)+(\.\d+))$/))
    Analytics_Longitude = get.longitude;
else
    Analytics_Longitude = 'undefined';
```

I am getting latitude and longitude value from http://www.telize.com/geoip in my js file now I want to validate that value using javascript...
Here I am getting this error like
**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

Comment: Maybe `Analytics_Longitude` is a callback and somewhere the is a call like `Analytics_Longitude()`

Comment: I am pushing the tracking value from http://www.telize.com/geoip into Analytics_Latitude and  Analytics_Longitude

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to regex the value, you got to check if it exists.

You can do this this way:

```
if(typeof get.latitude !== 'undefined'){...}
```

---

Second thing is that putting `()` between string and match seems to be wrong...

Change this:

```
(get.latitude).match(/((\d+)+(\.\d+))$/)
```

to this:

```
get.latitude.match(/((\d+)+(\.\d+))$/)
```

---

Third thing is that `latitude` is probably some float point number... so before acting as on string, you need to convert it:

```
get.latitude.toString().match(...)
```

Comment: Already I checked that I am getting value correctly, Now I need regular expression to validate that