# Why use regular expressions to validate latitude and longitude in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

When I [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=validate+latitude+longitude+%5Bjavascript%5D) for `validate latitude longitude [javascript]`, I get answers that [match digits indiscriminately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28211854/27358) or [match the wrong range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3518546/27358) or [are just too complicated to debug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18690202/27358).

In fairness, some of these OPs did *ask* for regexes, and Javascript isn't my first language, but it seems like it would be more straightforward and less error-prone just to do the math:

```
function isLatitude(maybeLat) {
  var latF = parseFloat(maybeLat)
  if (isNaN(latF)) return false
  return (latF >= -90 && latF <= 90)
}

function isLongitude(maybeLon) {
  var lonF = parseFloat(maybeLon)
  if (isNaN(lonF)) return false
  return lonF >= -180 && lonF <= 180
}
```

Yes, it's less terse, but it's a lot more readable than

```
^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$
```

Is there some advantage to using regular expressions? Performance? Browser compatibility? Library tools that only allow regex validation? SO users showing off their mad regex sk1llz?

Comment: No reason to use regex, although `parseFloat` will allow what would be a malformed lat/lng (e.g., `parseFloat('12a')` will return `12`. That may be what you want. Using `isFinite` and `Math.abs` will reject those.

Comment: Probably because there are several ways of denoting lat/lng, For instance DD MM.MMM (Degrees, Minutes, decimal minutes), DD.DDDD (Degrees, decimal degrees), DD MM SS (Degree, Minutes, Seconds) etc. So it maybe that they are trying to catch as many possible formats as possible

Comment: @PatrickEvans Ah. I totally forgot about that; but it's obvious--good thing you brought that up.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Can you make that an answer?

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for that -- I'd forgotten JavaScript didn't require explicit conversion of strings to numbers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I absolutely think this is overkill / unnecessary use of a regex.  I think your approach is correct, though it can be shortened somewhat:

```
function isLatitude(lat) {
  return isFinite(lat) && Math.abs(lat) <= 90;
}

function isLongitude(lng) {
  return isFinite(lng) && Math.abs(lng) <= 180;
}
```

`isFinite` will reject anything that isn't a (finite) number, or can't be automatically converted to a number (like a string containing a number).  Also, I've taken to using `lng` to represent longitude since it's the same length as `lat`, and can't be confused with a keyword.

The `Math` library functions (and `isFinite`) will automatically coerce strings to numbers, if possible.

Comment: Can you add a note to the answer pointing out for the JavaScript-inexperienced that the strings don't need to be converted to numbers before being passed to the math functions?

Comment: Done, @DavidMoles

Comment: It's returning true if lat is an empty string. I had return lat != "" && isFinite(lat) && Math.abs(lat) <= 90; to correct the problem

Comment: Hi, Patrick, you're correct about empty / whitespace-only strings -- annoyingly, JavaScript converts such strings to the number 0.  To be _really_ sure, you would probably want to add `(typeof lat !== 'string' || lat.trim() !== '')` but what a pain.  Some days it makes you want a typed language.  It works fine for me for "-.629218"....?

Comment: @EthanBrown No idea how stable it is, but loos good to me. I hope it will not create in production where I have thousands of users.

Answer (score 1):

One reason to use a regex may be to perform as-you-type partial string validation so as to prevent entry of an invalid value in the fist place, instead of catching an invalid final result after the user hits some submit button or key.

I suppose you could just try to coerce the string to a number and compare after each keystroke, but how does it deal with conversion of "-" and "." - I don't remember - its been many years since I cared about Javascript.
The FSM of a compiled regex will be more efficient than this conversion process but it would be insignificant in this case.